# Finding the other $x$-intecept of a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ when $a$ is unknown and one $x$-intercept is known

Tags: quadratics

One of the $x$-intercepts of the function $f(x)=ax^2-3x+1$ is at $x=-1$. Determine $a$ and the other $x$-intercept.

I happen to know that $a=-4$ and the other $x$-intercept is at $x=\frac{1}{4}$ but I don't know how to get there. I tried substituting $x=-1$ into the quadratic formula.

$$
-1=\frac{-(-3) \pm \sqrt{(-3)^2-4a}}{2a}
$$

Solving for $a$ I managed to come up with $a=-\frac {5}{2}$ by some convoluted process but obviously that doesn't work.

How do I properly solve for $a$, taking into account the known root of $x$?

Comment: You don't need the quadratic formula to determine $a$, just use $f(-1) = 0 \to a(-1)^2 - 3(-1) + 1 = a+4 = 0$.

Comment: If $-1$ is a root then $x-(-1)=x+1$ is a factor of $f(x)$, so $f(x) = ax^2-3x+1=(ax+b)(x+1)$. Then $b=1$ since $b\cdot1=1$, and $(a+b)x=-3x$ so $a+1=-3$, and $a=-4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is given in comment by Winther, here is another,
$ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ then $$r_1+r_2=\frac{-b}{a}$$ and $$r_1r_2=\frac{c}{a}$$

Comment: This method has the advantage that one does not need to calculate $a$ explicitly to get the second root as $x - 1 = \frac{3}{a}$ and $-x = \frac{1}{a} \to x-1 = -3x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ and $s$ are roots of $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ then $x-r$ and $x-s$ are [factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) of $f(x)$.  Therefore,
$$
f(x) = a(x - r)(x - s) = a \bigl( x^2 - (r + s)x + rs \bigr),
$$
so
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
-a(r + s) &= b \\
ars &= c
\end{align}
\right.
$$
If the coefficients $b$ and $c$ are known, as well as one root $s$, then we have a system of two equations with two unknowns.  Multiplying the first equation by $s$ and adding the two equations together yields
$$
-as^2 = bs + c,
$$
so the leading coefficient$\Large^\dagger$ is
$$
a = - \frac{bs + c}{s^2}.
$$
Then the other root is
$$
r = \frac{c}{as} = - \frac{cs}{bs + c}.
$$

$\Large^\dagger$ I am assuming that that $c \ne 0$ and, hence, that neither of the roots were zero.  I leave that special (and easier) case to you.